# How to i know if this graph is directed or undirected?

Tags: data-structures, graph

My teacher didnt specify what kind of graph is this so im confused how to answer some of the questions. Need help to identify if this is directed or undirected graph
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to check that your graph is undirected is, once the adjacency matrix is provided is to notice that it is symmetric, if the graph is directed it cannot be simmetric because it would be an entry which A_i,j different of A_j,i.